# How we can know is there a specific variable in C++ or not?

Tags: c++, variables

In C++, before define a new variable, how we can find out is there a variable with this name or not?

Comment: Just define the variable and check for compilation errors.

Comment: Grep the source tree?

Comment: You know because C++ is not a dynamic language. It's possible to figure out exactly what variables are defined at any given time, including while you're writing code. If your scope is so wide that you're having trouble telling what is and isn't defined, you're doing something very wrong.

Comment: Or you just write cout << VariableName; if it compiles, it exists, and you see its value

Comment: Note - if you define a variable in a one scope which already exists in a wider scope, the instance in the inner scope will *hide* the instance in the outer scope.  If you try to redefine one in the same scope, you will get a compiler error due to ODR.

Answer (score 8):

You can turn on compiler option for warning if a variable is shadowing another one. For instance for GCC this option is `-Wshadow`.

Comment: Well I in run-time mode I can not do this. I should be sure about presence of this variable, if it is not there I will define it.

Comment: @Chavoosh: C++ doesn't work like that. It is always possible to tell at compile time whether a particular name is in scope or not.

Comment: you mean I can not define any variable or something like array after compile??

Comment: You can - but then you wrote that action in the source code. And you can see there if you used a name before.

Comment: Well @Henno, consider that I want define new array with fixed size when I need it, If I define a function in my program for this, can I define new array in runtime?

Comment: As C++ is not interactive, **YOU** (the person) will not be able to define a new variable.
In your code, try something like
if(needArray){ std::vector<widget> v; v.push_back(Widget); }

Comment: uhuuum... I think I got it! So see am I right? I can not define new variable by myself, but if I put a `if statement` in my codes, the program-itself-can define it, if the condition be right...ok?

Comment: @Henno, In this condition, how I can check that a variable was defined or not? I mean which statement I should use if `if statement` to do this?

Comment: @Chavoosh You are thinking in a completely un-C++-like way.
What do you want to accomplish?
When in your program, a condition determines that a new variable needs to be constructed, you write that. 
I do not get what your problem is with that - the condition? The name of the variable?

Comment: OK...I hope I can explain it good. Suppose you want define new array with this name: `new_array`. You want define it,JUST if there is not another array with this name. Suppose I need check this condition in one place of my program and if there was not an array with name of `new_array` then I will define it... I hope it be clear...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/39753/discussion-between-henno-and-chavoosh)

Answer (score 2):

You should search all parent classes and that class with grep in text mode. And if you use a development studio program like Microsoft visual studio, you can type variable name and wait for auto-cast, it will show if the variable exists.

Answer (score 0):

In general, C++ doesn't have reflection mechanisms, so you can't really check if a variable is defined using C++ code.

You have to use 3rd party tools for that.